# SQLAlchemy: Inserting into table with dynamically-created name

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a table whose name must be created dynamically. Here is how the table is created:

```py
def create_data_table(table_name):
    meta = Base.metadata
    my_table= Table(
        table_name, meta,
        Column('id', BigInteger, primary_key=True, nullable=False),
        Column('file_name', String(250), nullable=False)
    )
    meta.create_all(engine, [my_table])
```

This works just fine. However, I also need to pass the table name as a variable when I insert rows, and that's where I am running into problems.

Here are the things I have tried:

```py
def insert_data(table_name, data):

    meta = Base.metadata
    my_table = Table(
        table_name, meta,
        Column('id', BigInteger, primary_key=True),
        Column('file_name', String(250))
    )
    conn = engine.connect()
    conn.execute(my_table.insert(), data)
```

This results in an error, telling me that my_table is already defined in my metadata.

To avoid this, I have tried creating a class instead:

```py
class my_table(Base):
    __tablename__ = ''
    id = Column('id', String(50), primary_key=True)
    file_name = Column('file_name', String(250))

    def __init__(self, table_name, id, file_name):
        __tablename__ = table_name
        self.id = id
        self.file_name = file_name
```

Again, I was able to create the table without any problems, but SQLAlchemy did not allow me to pass the table name as a parameter when I tried to insert rows.

Ideally, I would like to use the first approach. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQLAlchemy `MetaData` object has a mapping of all of the tables it holds through the [`MetaData.tables`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.tables) attribute. Which is:

> A dictionary of Table objects keyed to their name or “table key”.

You do not want to recreate the `Table` either directly or through the declarative mapping, just access it by name from `MetaData.tables`. E.g.:

```py
Base.metadata.tables[table_name]
```

Your `insert_data()` implementation can simply be:

```py
def insert_data(table_name, data):
    my_table = Base.metadata.tables[table_name]
    conn = engine.connect()
    conn.execute(my_table.insert(), data)
```

Comment: One extra problem - If my program restarts and the table was previously created with the above method, using `table_data = Base.metadata.tables[table_name]` for queries cannot find the table, even though it already exists. Any advice? Thanks! @SuperShoot

Comment: Found the solution myself; it works just adding `Base.metadata.reflect(engine)`. Thanks!